Where is the ordering of Windows Regedit "Favorites" menu stored?
Where does Windows Regedit store the ordering of its "Favorites" menu (ordered by date-ascending)?
Regedit favorites are located here:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit\Favorites
Regedit's "Favorites" menu displays these favorites descending in the order they were created.
I'm trying to find where this ordering is stored in order to edit higher-up entries. If I try editing the favorites registry values themselves, e.g. to replace the first/menu-top entry with a different key, it immediately moves this entry to the bottom of the Favorites menu as a fresh/new favorite entirely.
Is there some sort of hash table somewhere that Regedit compares against in order to keep track of favorites date/ordering?

As far as I can see, Regedit doesn't store the order anywhere; what you're seeing is just the enumeration order of the registry values as provided by RegEnumValue(), which apparently corresponds to the insertion order most of the time (although there is no guarantee that it will), i.e. creating a new value always places it at the bottom.

I experimented by exporting the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit\Favorites key, editing the order in Notepad, deleting the key, then importing the edited .reg file. The favourites in RegEdit were now in the order I put them in. (I did it in a Windows Sandbox and used an old version of RegAlyzer for the export and import.)
